# How to show the existence of global minimizer of Lasso type of objective function?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, optimization, lasso, regularization, high-dimensional

Suppose the objective function to be minimized is
$$F(\theta) = \|y - X \theta\|_2^2 + \sum_{i=1}^p \lambda_i |\theta_i|$$
where $\theta$ is the independent variable which is feasible in $\mathbb{R}^p$. Other quantities $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, $X \in\mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$, individual penalties $\lambda_i \geq 0$ are all fixed. Note that some $\lambda_i$'s might be zero. We focus on
high dimension so $p>n$.

$F(\theta)$ is convex. But how to show that there exists $\widehat{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^p$ such that for any $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p$, $F(\theta) \geq F(\widehat{\theta})$?

Comment: $F$ is bounded below by $0$ and is continuous, whence it has at least one local minimum.  Consider the behavior of $F$ on the line segment connecting any two local minima, given that $F$ is convex.  The result is immediate.

Comment: Could you show more details about the existence of local minimum? I think $e^x$, $x \in\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and bounded below by zero but it does not have a local minimum.

Comment: I hope someone can go through this specific case with you. But in general, the strategy for establishing optimality of nonsmooth, convex problems like yours is to use the notion of subdifferential operator $\nabla F$. The point $\mathbf{x}$ such that $\mathbf{0}\in \nabla F(\mathbf{x})$ is an optimum almost by definition of the subgradient. Proof strategy is: 1) show that for any $\mathbf{x}$ satisfying the subdifferential condition, we have global optimality 2) show that this set is nonempty (though potentially not unique if $\mathbf{X}$ is not full rank and some $\lambda_i$ are zero).

Comment: The missing detail is that by using a crude estimate you can limit the domain to a bounded, compact set which is not minimized on its boundary.  (Simply choose ridiculously large values for the components of $\theta.$) That distinguishes this $F$ from your exponential example.

Comment: I guess the set might be $\{\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p: F(\theta) \leq F(\theta^{(0)})\}$. This set can be shown as closed. If I can show that is is bounded, then the problem is done. But how to show this set is bounded, given $X$ is not of full rank?

Comment: Why should the rank of $X$ be relevant?  (That's a hint.  If it's not clear, contemplate the situation where $X$ is a zero matrix.  We do need all penalties to be nonzero, though -- and this thought experiment helps show why.)  Another hint: it's easy to show that for all $i,$ $|\theta_i|\le ||y||^2/\lambda_i$ when $\theta$ minimizes $F.$

Answer (score 1):

> Could you show more details about the existence of local minimum? I think $e^x$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and bounded below by zero but it does not have a local minimum.

If you add two functions with a global minimum, then the result must have a global minimum as well.

Also, because the two added functions are convex the result must be convex as well and the global minimum will be a unique global minimum.